# Fabric.JS compound object cropped by boundaries

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, hammer.js

I initialize a canvas and add an image to it.

```
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
        hoverCursor: 'pointer',
        selection: false,
        allowTouchScrolling: false,
});


fabric.Image.fromURL(file_path, (img) => {
 //  After the image is uploaded, scaleRatio is calculated with  Math.round(((img.height + img.width) / 2) * 0.05), capped at 80
 // extendFabricLineToArrow function is called afterwards
});

extendFabricLineToArrow() { 
    let scaleR = this.scaleRatio;
    try {
      fabric.LineArrow = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {
        type: 'lineArrow',
        initialize: function (element, options) {
          options || (options = {});
          this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);
        },
        toObject: function () {
          return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'));
        },
        _render: function (ctx) {
          this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
          if (this.width === 0 || this.height === 0 || !this.visible) return;
          ctx.save();
          let xDiff = this.x2 - this.x1;
          let yDiff = this.y2 - this.y1;
          let angle = Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff);
          ctx.translate((this.x2 - this.x1) / 2, (this.y2 - this.y1) / 2);
          ctx.rotate(angle);
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(Math.abs(scaleR), 0);
          ctx.lineTo(-Math.abs(scaleR), Math.abs(scaleR));
          ctx.lineTo(-Math.abs(scaleR), -Math.abs(scaleR));

          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fillStyle = this.stroke;
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.restore();
        }
      });
  fabric.LineArrow.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
    callback && callback(new fabric.LineArrow([object.x1, object.y1, object.x2, object.y2], object));
  };
  fabric.LineArrow.async = true;
  fabric.LineArrow.perPixelTargetFind = this.perPixelTargetFind;
  fabric.LineArrow.targetFindTolerance = this.targetFindTolerance;
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error from extendFabric fct', e);
}
```

}

The arrow is created with the code :

```
fabric.LineArrow([x1, y1, x2, y2], { // with x2, y2 being the TIP of the arrow
        strokeWidth: this.stroke_width,
        fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        stroke: this.color,
        padding: this.stroke_width
});
```

HammerJS is used for pinch functionality

```
hammer.on('pinch', (ev) => {
        let point = new fabric.Point(ev.center.x, ev.center.y)
        let delta = this.zoom * ev.scale;
        this.canvas.zoomToPoint(point, delta);
        this.canvas.renderAll();
});
```

In the process of pinching, the tip of the arrow gets cropped by the what should be old object boundaries resulting in the object being deformed.

A video example can be found on this link https://share.vlinde.com/index.php/s/Rb29XbQMEfg4myP

FabricJS version : 2.3.5
HammerJS v : 2.0.8

Comment: You can make `objectCaching =false` for `fabric.LineArrow` objects, or you need to draw your objects inside the bounding box properly.

Comment: that totally worked ! thank you